# Multidimensional Array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

How do I print out the array going up the columns, starting with the last column and last row, and working backwards to the first column and row.  I get an OutOfBoundsException. I believe the problem is with my inner loop.

It should look like this 
                                                                            89, 66, 21, 90, 54, 
etc....

```
        {33, 92, 54},
        {22, 43, 90},
        {26, 85, 21},
        {75, 14, 66},
        { 8, 49, 89}

    };
    for(col=2; col<stuff.length; col++)
    {
        for(row=4; row<stuff.length; row--)
        {
            System.out.print(stuff[row][col] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Please add a language tag

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have two problems. The first is that your first loop starts at 2 and then proceeds to count up. This means it will only print the last row. I believe you need to change the `col++` to a `col--` as well as changing it from a `col<stuff.length` to a `col>=0`. The second `for` requires a similar change from `row<stuff.length` to `row>=0`. The IndexOutOfBounds will come from the inner loop entering a infinite loop counting down which will eventually cause it to try and access your array with a negative value.

Comment: Thanks that worked! However I would like to keep the .length property

Comment: then use it in the declaration or `row` and `col` with a decrement of 1: `col = stuff[0].length - 1` and `row=stuff.length - 1`

Answer (score 0):

1) Your loop starts on col 2 and counts up, which means only the last column will be printed

2) You need to change the outer loop counter to stop once it is smaller than 0 so that an infinite loop is not caused

3) You need to do the same for the inner loop and make sure it counts until 0 and stops

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming stuff is your  two dimentional array. 
stuff.length will always return no of rows, to get no. of columns you need to do stuff[0].length

Solution of above problem is here:

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int A[][] = {{33,92,54},
               {22,43,90},
               {26,85,21},
               {75,14,66},
               {8,49,89}};
        int rowCount = A.length;
        int colCount = A[0].length;

        System.out.println("rows:"+rowCount);
        System.out.println("cols:"+colCount);
        for(int j= colCount-1; j>=0;j--){
            for (int i = rowCount-1;i>=0;i--){
                System.out.print(A[i][j] +",");
            }

        }

    }
```